# How to get the featured image and put it's image path in to inline styles ie. <div style="background:url(filepath/here)";>?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-image

I've got this line of code -

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('latest-img'); ?>
```

which is pulling in the correct featured image, however when I try and put -

```
<div class="blog-image" style="background:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail('latest-img'); ?>');"></div>
```

it doesn't show.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you write <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('latest-img'); ?></div> what's the output? if you take that output and put it into <div class="blog-image" style="background:url('_____'); ?>');"></div> does it work? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: That's just giving me my featured image wrapped inside a div ie - <div><img src="link/to/image"/></div>. Which is what I have already, however I need it to be a background image and it needs to be dynamic (so no hardcoding image paths).

Comment: If that's the case, then you want to pull out some of that. You don't want `<div><img src="` and you don't want `"/></div>` Only the link to image.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but when I try <div class="blog-image" style="background:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail('latest-img'); ?>');"></div> it comes up with an error like this - ');"> - which is not what I want.

Comment: From wordpress.stackexchange (or many other quick google searches also) [see here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115954/featured-image-as-background-image-on-pages)

Comment: I personally don't know php, but I feel like you would want to change your php to get only the link to the image, and not those image tags. You could place your php piece in some other part of the page, hidden, and then use javascript to get the innerHTML of that part. That would get your string with the img tags into javascript. From there you replace the image tags with nothing, and change the background property of your target div using javascript. If you can get php to give you what you want, that will be the most elegant solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get ID of the post, then get thumbnail ID of the post and use it to get URL of the thumbnail:

```
<?php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'latest-img' );
?>
```

then include URL of image in style of div:

```
<div class="blog-image" style="background:url('<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>');"></div>
```